# Tkinter/Pyautogui and Automation

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui, tkinter-entry

wondered if anyone could help with this problem I'm facing.

Attempting to automate a traceroute through Winbox by using Tkinter and Pyautogui, the issue is getting Pyautogui to enter the IP address entered into the TK entry box and then typewriting it to Winbox.

It can currently enter any normal number into winbox's IP field, however, it malfunctions when you attempt to enter an IP that uses fullstops. Here is the errorcode:

```
line 30, in Trace
    int_answers = int(Ent1.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '192.168.0.1'
```

code:

```
import pyautogui as pt
from time import sleep
import pyperclip
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("AutoNet")
root.geometry("400x400")

sleep(3)
vT = IntVar()
Ent1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=vT, show=None,  font=("Arial", 12), fg="Grey")
Ent1.grid(row=1, column=1)


def Trace():
    global x, y


    position = pt.locateOnScreen("win.png", confidence=.6)
    x = position[0]
    y = position[1]

    pt.moveTo(x, y, duration=.5)
    pt.moveTo(x + 125, y - -60, duration=.5)
    pt.doubleClick()
    pt.press('del')
    int_answers = int(Ent1.get())
    pt.typewrite(str(int_answers))



btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='Traceroute', justify='center', font=("Arial", 10), command=Trace)
btn1.grid(row=1, column=3)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you making it an integer, why not just pass it as a string

Comment: That is a good question. >.< I eventually just bypassed it with pyperclip and chromedriver to get the IP from a CRM.